# C/C++ [GCC] - How to determine if library code is compiled as static (.a) or dynamic (.so)?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a C/C++ dynamic library which some users compile and use as static. The issue arises where I have a constructor/deconstructor in my dynamic library which causes an error when compiling as static:

```
static void __attribute__((constructor)) Load()
{
}

static void __attribute__((destructor)) Unload()
{
}
```

My question is this - does GCC offer a macro which determines how the library will be compiled? Something I can use around my constructor/destructor as shown below, for example:

```
#ifdef GCC_LIB_SHARED   // Ideally looking for a macro so I can do this.
static void __attribute__((constructor)) Load()
{
}

static void __attribute__((destructor)) Unload()
{
}
#endif
```

I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: Hmm - the compiler and preprocessor can't know this ahead of link time.

Comment: That's what I thought since a compiler flag determines static or shared. Was hoping I might get lucky by asking here.

Comment: That's just a shortcut. It's actually two independent phases, compiling each `.c` to `.o`, then linking all the `.o` with the libraries. The linker flags aren't used by the compiler phase.

Comment: If you ask about the error you get, then perhaps we can help you solve that instead?

Comment: You could define your own macro on the compiler command line if it cannot be detected automatically.

Comment: @IanAbbott - I think this is the only real strategy.